# How to create a user record using factory girl and cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I have never used factory girl and I started testing from this week so all this new stuff just making me crazy. Can anyone explain me a simple way to create a record using factory girl.

Here is the use case. I already created a test using cucumber where it creates a user and also create other records like account, user categories. Now I am writing second test case where I say there should be no test data(I can use data created from first test but dont want dependency from other test cases.). So I want to use factory girl to create a user for me and associated user records. Here my test which works without using factory girl.

```
@no-database-cleaner
Feature: Managing users parent child relationships
  In order to use portal
  I want to create parent child relationships

  Scenario:  Creating a child user 
    Given I am on the homepage

    When I attempt to sign in with following user account:
      | email address         | password |
      | abc@company1.com   | password |

    Then I should see "abc@company1.com" message on page
    When I follow "All Child Users"
    Then I should see "Add Sub Child"
    When I click "Add Sub Child"
    Then I should see "Child Sub User"
    And I fill in "Email" with "xyztest@gmail.com"
    And I select "Medium" from "user_filter"
    And I choose "abc_id_yes"
    When I press "Create Child User"
    Then I should see "Child User is successfully created."
    And appropriate records should get created for the child user for new abc_id
```

And in step definition I have code like

```
Then(/^appropriate records should get created for the child user for new abc_id$/) do
  parent_user = User.find_by_email("abc@company1.com")
  user = User.find_by_email("xyztest@gmail.com")
  account = Account.find_by_user_id(parent_user)
  user.default_filter_level.should be_true
  user.ar_id.should be_true
  user.parent_id.should == parent_user.id
  filter = Filter.find_by_user_id(user.id)
  filter.user_id.should == user.id
  filter.abc_id.should be_true
  filter.account_id.should == account.id
end
```

So how I can achieve same result using factory girl which will also create a associated records. Thanks

Comment: Show us the test that isn't working. What you have here wouldn't benefit from FactoryGirl, since there's nothing to set up.

Comment: I want to use factory girl for above test. Can you please explain me why factory girl is not useful for above test? All I want to make sure that when I run above test there should be no test data and if there is no test data above test fails. So using factory girl I can create/insert record to tables and use the above steps.

Comment: So, there's a `Given` that's missing? If you can show the error that you're seeing it would help a lot in figuring out what you're trying to do. FactoryGirl is just a builder for models, so likely you have some model data missing. But we don't know which unless you show us the error(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are true that other tests should not depend on this one. For other scenarios, add a `Given an user with other models exists` step with the following definition:

```
Given(/^an user with other models exists$/) do
  parent = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "xyztest@gmail.com" parent_id: parent)
  account = FactoryGirl.create(:account, user_id: user.id)
  FactoryGirl.create(:filter, user_id: user.id, account_id: account.id)
end
```

In spec/factories/users.rb (you specify the default attribute values, but you can override them in the `FactoryGirl.create()` call):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "abc@company1.com"
    default_filter_level true
    ar_id true
  end
end
```

In spec/factories/filters.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :filter do
    abc_id true
  end
end
```

In spec/factories/accounts.rb (It's just an empty factory, you can specify the attributes you often need to have assigned.):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do

  end
end
```

Note that in the last step in the scenario, you should not test whether the appropriate models are created:

```
And appropriate records should get created for the child user for new abc_id
```

Instead use something like this:

```
When I follow "All Child Users"
Then the page should have newly created child user
```

Comment: Can I put users.rb under features/support/factories.rb. I do not have spec.

Comment: On create user I alos create Account, Filter. Relationship between them are has_one :account, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :filter, :dependent => :destroy so using your code will take care of this or I have to write a logic to create account and filter in factory girl. sorry if this sound stupid today is my first day of factory girl

Comment: You can specify other directory for FactoryGirl in `config/application.rb` like this: http://blog.jetthoughts.com/2011/09/24/change-factory-girl-directory-path-for-rails-3-generator/

Comment: And with those relationships you can try something like this: `factory :user do
    email "abc@company1.com"
    default_filter_level true
    ar_id true
    account create(:account)
    filter create(:filter)
  end`

Comment: getting error when I am trying to create filter and acount saying Attribute already defined: create (FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError)

Comment: You can use `association filter` instead of `filter create(:filter)`. If it does not help, post new question with failing code.