# Factory_girl/Capybara and Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, factory-bot

In my Rails projects I normally use `factory_girl` to build/create users in my app. I want to know if I can use `factory_girl` when using Cucumber, Capybara to test the user interaction with my app. There is no database to save them to, I am only looking to store their credentials

I can have many users so wanted to create factories for each user (unless there is a better way of doing this with Cucumber).

Within my support folder could I create a factories folder and then a .rb file holding each user.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_1 do
    username "username"
    password "password"
  end
end
```

Within my `env.rb` file I am requiring Factory Girl but this is not enough

```
require 'factory_girl'
```

As if in my feature I try

```
Then(/^I will enter my credentials$/) do
  fill_in 'username', :with => user_1.email
  fill_in 'password', :with => user_2.password
  click_button 'login-button'
end
```

I get

```
uninitialized constant user_1
```

I also have a feeling that if this is to work I need a before hook that will build the factory user but I'm unsure on the whole setup at the moment.

Does anyone use factory_girl in this way or, as I mentioned earlier, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do seething like this

```
Given(/^I will enter my credentials$/) do
  @user = user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end
```

you can read more on this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/16841999/4421094 it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarshallCap for the answer, I had come up with a workable solution and wanted to share, maybe its right or maybe there is a better way but this is what I have ended up doing, if this helps someone else then great.

Firstly I created a class for my `factory_users`

```
class Users
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user_1, :class => :users do |u|
      u.skip_create
      u.username "username1"
      u.password "password"
    end
  end

 FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :user_2, :class => :users do |u|
     u.skip_create
     u.username "username2"
     u.password "password2"
   end
 end
end
```

require `factory_girl` in `env.rb`

```
require 'factory_girl'
```

And within my login script within step_definitions assigned an instance variable a hash of the users attributes

```
Then(/^I will enter my credentials$/) do
 @user = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user_1)
 fill_in 'username', :with => @user[:username]
end
```